# Unable to save data on LocalStorage with a class instance method

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, local-storage

I'm trying to save some data in LocalStorage.

I'm trying to do it using a class.

The constructor will gather the information from the form.

And a class method will try to save it.

The problem is that only the email part is being saved (using chrome)(in a strange way).
see picture attached below.

[image]

Anybody knows whats the problem?
Many thanks

update:
seems to work at firefox. and not in chrome as described earlier.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<main>
<section>
    <form>
    <label for="txtFullName">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtFullName">
    <label for="txtUsername">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtUsername">
    <label for="txtEmail">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="txtEmail">
    <label for="txtPsw">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="txtPsw">
    <input type="button" id="btnRegister" value="Register">           
    </form>
</section>      
<section>
    <label for="txtLoginEmail">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="txtLoginEmail">
    <label for="txtLoginPsw">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="txtLoginPsw">
    <input type="button" id="btnLogin" value="Login"> 
</section>
</main>

<script>
'use strict';

document.getElementById("btnRegister").addEventListener("click", function(){
    let registerAttempt = new HandleRegister();
    registerAttempt.saveRegister();
    //validateLogin();
});

document.getElementById("btnLogin").addEventListener("click", function(){
    //let loginAttempt = new HandleLogin();
    //loginAttempt.checkLogin();
});




class HandleRegister{

    constructor(){
        this.fullName= document.getElementById('txtFullName').value;
        this.userName= document.getElementById('txtUsername').value;
        this.email= document.getElementById('txtEmail').value;
        this.password= document.getElementById('txtPsw').value;
        //alert (`${this.fullName} ${this.userName} ${this.email} ${this.password}`);
    }

    saveRegister(){
        var storage = window.localStorage;
        alert (`${this.fullName} ${this.userName} ${this.email} ${this.password}`);
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            if (storage.fullName == undefined){
                storage.fullName= this.fullName;
                alert('saved'+this.fullName);
            }else{
                alert('fullname already saved');
            }

            if (storage.userName == undefined){
                storage.userName= this.userName;
                alert('saved'+this.userName);
            }else{
                alert('userName already saved');
            }

            if (storage.password == undefined){
                storage.password= this.password;
                alert('saved'+this.password);
            }else{
                alert('fullname already saved');
            }

            if (storage.email == undefined){
                storage.email= this.fullName;
                alert('saved'+this.email);
            }else{
                alert('email already saved');
            }
            alert ('saving completed');
        }else{
            alert("your browser don\'t support localstorage");
        }
    }



}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My guess is that you managed to save the email at some earlier point in time, and the current code doesn't save anything. It's because you have `typeof(Storage)` instead of `typeof(storage)`.

Comment: I really think you should be using a tool like [jquery](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/) and [storejs](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/)

Comment: @ChrisG Storage is the Constructor of `window.localStorage`, that part is not the problem

Comment: You need to use *setItem* and *getItem*. Have a look at the specs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @Robert nope they don't **need to**, Storage object's own properties should call `getItem` at get* and `setItem` at set. (*if defined). Ps: MDN is no *specs*.

Comment: @Kaiido Right; should have caught this due to SO coloring `Storage` cyan. However I can't replicate this, the above code works for me as-is.

Comment: The screenshot is exactly what I got on jsfiddle. @codingnighter2000 you shouldn't copy-paste blocks around your code; that's what functions are for. I'd assign a `name` attribute to each input, then iterate over them and use the `name` as localStorage key. That way you can greatly reduce the amount of code and avoid errors like the one described by Kaiido.

Comment: Ah now I can see what you've done: You did resize the window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug8WA.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/d26PR.png